# How can I condense the citing box in a multi-row table?

Tags: citing, tabularx

I want to cite inside a multi-row table where the citing box becomes horizontally longer than it should be.

My code:

```tex
\documentclass[journal,onecolumn]{IEEEtran}
% \documentclass[letterpaper,10pt,conference]{IEEEtran}
\ifCLASSOPTIONcompsoc
    \usepackage[nocompress]{cite}
\else
    \usepackage{cite}
\fi

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{pifont}
\newcommand{\xmark}{\ding{55}}
\newcommand{\cmark}{\ding{51}}
%
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\newcommand{\n}{\\}
\newcommand{\reduce}{\linespread{0.8}\selectfont}
% for the second table
\newcommand{\splitcell}[1]{%
    \linespread{0.8}\selectfont\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}%
}\begin{document}

\title{}
\author{}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
\end{abstract}

\section{Previous Work}
\begin{table}[!htp]
    \caption{Comparative table of highlighted studies.}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{lm{4cm}l}
      \toprule
      Study                              & Goal                                        &  Approach    \\
      \midrule
      \cite{networkx} & Scheduling large workflows onto ... ... ... & HEFT, MinMin \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}\label{table:comparative}
\end{table}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{workflow}
\end{document}
```

workflow.bib

```
@electronic{networkx,
title={NetworkX},
url = {https://networkx.org},
lastvisited = {2022-04-04}
}
```

output:

[image]

Here the citing box colored in green is horizontally longer than it should be, I have no idea cause of this.

Wanted style example for the citing box is:

[image]

Comment: Do you really want/need the default boxes instead of colored text for links? For some people (me too) that boxes are a weird ugly default. If you don't know what I'm talking about, just try the  `colorlinks` option on `hyperref` package.

Comment: BTW, `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` is actually load by default.  You can omit this line with not very old TeX installations.

Comment: @Fran I think if the citing show up as numbers, automatically colored box shows up. But instead if the citing show up as `Author_surname date` like you said instead of colored boxes colored text for the links is show up. I believe this differs journal format to journal formal.

Comment: No. The color box is the default of hyperref for any link (not only cites) but with `\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}` you will see "[1]" without the box but with  "1" green, not black.  Adding  also ` ,citecolor=blue` you can change the ugly green to a nice blue, for example, and this work also  to cites with author-year format. On the other hand, you provided a minimal **no** working example because   there are no any `workflow.bib` to test, but using another .bib file and changing the cite to an existen bib key, I obtain a box around 1 almost square, i.e., of the expected height.

Comment: I am sorry I have added `workflow.bib` example file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

Without touch anything of your example, just compile with `xelatex`.

**Solution 2:**

Convert your  working example in a true **minimal** working example. Trying to remove  all the really superfluous to reproduce the issue necessarily leads you to try to remove the `cite` package, and then, the problem disappear also with `pdflatex` and `lualatex`, and therefore this package is causing the bug.

the example reduced to a MWE that reproduce the issue only when the is loaded the `cite` package *and* is not used `xelatex`:

```
\documentclass[journal,onecolumn]{IEEEtran}
%\usepackage{cite}  
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{lp{4cm}}
      \cite{networkx} & foo \par foo \par  foo \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{workflow}
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

Comment: Ah also `\usepackage{breakcites}` was causing this!